# Why does ruby method with = at the end not allow more then one argument

Tags: ruby

This is in a shared library, I have to make this backward compatible.

Original method

```
   def rrp_exc_sales_tax=(num)
      price_set(1, num, currency_code)
   end
```

Need to enhance and add currency_code

```
   def rrp_exc_sales_tax=(num, currency_code=nil)
      print "num=#{num}"
      print "currency_code=#{currency_code}"
      price_set(1, num, currency_code)
   end


some_class.rrp_exc_sales_tax=2, "USD"

num=[2, "USD"]
currency_code=
```

No value gets assigned to currency_code

Comment: To the folks who are downvoting and requesting to close, this raises a good question about the ruby language and how features are implemented. Please consider before pushing people out of the site.

Comment: setter methods(e.g. methods ending in `=`) should be reserved for setting instance variables through assignment `=`. In you case it would be better to convert this to a true method call since assignment does not occur inside your method. The original design is flawed at its core by using `=` can you please post the price set method so as to allow us to see how assignment is occurring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be backwards compatible, leverage on the powers of the array:

```
def rrp_exc_sales_tax=(arr)
  num, currency_code = arr
  price_set(1, num, currency_code)
end

some_class.rrp_exc_sales_tax=2, "USD"
# => num=2
# => currency_code="USD"

some_class.rrp_exc_sales_tax=2
# => num=2
# => currency_code=nil
```

Comment: @archie - updated my answer to be backwards-compatible

Comment: +1 excellent answer **Update** even if it defies standard convention of setter methods.

Comment: That will work and looks very clean rather then the if is_a? solutions, which also work. Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to use strike-out on your original answer, just to have something else. If we want to, we can see your changes by looking at the edit history. Simply remove the old stuff and enter what you want your answer to read-as; The result will be less visually noisy.

Comment: @theTinMan - you are right, I removed the old answer

Answer (score 3):

Because it's meant to look like a simple assignment operation. If that operation needs to be parameterized, it makes more sense to make it look like a method call instead. Also, having multi-parameter assignment statements complicates the language grammar.

Comment: Is there a reference to ruby documentation, so I can explain to the team.

Comment: this is not actually `assignment` but a setter method. `assignment` should/would occur inside the setter method. They are similar in syntax but not the same in functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You should try it like this:-

```
def rrp_exc_sales_tax(num, currency_code=nil)
  print "num=#{num}"
  print "currency_code=#{currency_code}"
  price_set(1, num, currency_code)
end
```

For maintaining backward compatibility, you can do like this:

```
def rrp_exc_sales_tax=(num)
  if num.is_a?(Hash)
    print "num=#{num["num"]}"
    print "currency_code=#{num["currency_code"]}"
    price_set(1, num["num"], num["currency_code"])
  else
    print "num=#{num}"
    print "currency_code=#{currency_code}"
    price_set(1, num, currency_code)
  end 
end
```

Now, in new implementation, you will call it like this:-

```
rrp_exc_sales_tax={"num"=>2, "currency_code" => "USD"}
```

and it will maintain backward compatibility as well.

Comment: You could also add a `num.is_a? Array` branch to allow `o.rrp_exc_sales_tax = [ 2, "USD" ]`.

Comment: @muistooshort: Yes array will also equally serve the purpose, I feel by hash one knows which variable represents what.